# How to properly escape "discourged" XML characters?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

[Per the XML 1.0 standard,](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets) there is a character range which is considered "discouraged": 
I would like to escape these characters (such as smart quote “, dec 147, or ’ (dec 146)) inside of XML attribute values using their hex encoded XML entity string.

I noticed when looking at the file in Chrome or Edge for example, it shows me the actual value, such as `"&#0093;"`. I have also tried `"&amp;#0093;"`, but that works the same as well.

To be clear, I'm attempting to render these "discouraged" characters in an attribute, like follows:

This:

```
<foo bar="&#0093;">
```

Should be rendered/interepreted by a parser as this:

```
<foo bar="“">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a trailing semicolon to terminate the entity reference:

```
<foo bar="&#0093;">
```

Comment: hi, sorry, my example had the typo - but real code certainly has the trailing semicolon. It does not work. I've updated my post - thank you for your help!